# How to delete only one row from non unique set of rows in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have this table

```
create table order_details(
    id_of_product integer,
    id_of_person text
)
```

both fields are not unique. How to delete one row from the table with specified **id_of_product** and **id_of_person**

for example i need to delete one row with id of 6 P.S person is the same for this set of rows

[image: sample data]

Comment: So after deleting, you want 3 rows with `id_of_product = 6` in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use system column [ctid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) to specify particular row, even if it has no unique values.

```
WITH u AS 
(
    SELECT distinct on (id_of_product, id_of_person) id_of_product, id_of_person, ctid 
    FROM order_details
)
DELETE FROM order_details 
WHERE id_of_product=6 AND id_of_person='ey...' AND ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM u)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the internal column `ctid` to pick a unique row to be deleted:

```
delete from order_details
where id_of_product = 6
  and ctid = (select min(ctid) 
              from order_details 
              where id_of_product = 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: don't you have other columns that you can use to further filtering or ordering uniquely the results?
The resultset could come back [in different orders](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235300/postgesql-non-deterministic-order-of-result-with-limit-and-order-by) if more rows are equal.

If instead you have a way to determine uniquely the order, you can achieve it. For example, creating the table with the additional `change_dt` column and inserting some data

```
create table order_details(
    id_of_product integer,
    id_of_person text,
    change_dt timestamp default now()
);

insert into order_details values (6, 'A');
insert into order_details values (6, 'A');
insert into order_details values (6, 'A');
insert into order_details values (6, 'A');
insert into order_details values (7, 'A');
```

You can see that the columns can now be ordered uniquely

```
select *, 
    rank() over (partition by id_of_product, id_of_person order by change_dt) rnk 
from order_details;
```

Result

```
 id_of_product | id_of_person |         change_dt          | rnk
---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.627656 |   1
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.870108 |   2
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.899382 |   3
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.919873 |   4
             7 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:40.013748 |   1
(5 rows)
```

you can now delete, for example, the "2nd oldest" `6-A` row (`change_dt = 2022-08-09 09:33:39.870108`) with:

```
delete from order_details where
(id_of_product, id_of_person, change_dt) = 
    (
    select id_of_product, id_of_person, change_dt
    from
        (select *, 
            rank() over (partition by id_of_product, id_of_person order by change_dt) rnk 
        from order_details 
        where id_of_product=6 and id_of_person='A') ranking
    where rnk=2
    )
;
```

Result

```
 id_of_product | id_of_person |         change_dt          |
---------------+--------------+----------------------------+
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.627656 |
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.899382 |
             6 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:39.919873 |
             7 | A            | 2022-08-09 09:33:40.013748 |
```

Edit: as other suggest, you can also use the `ctid` column, but I believe you would want to delete a "precise" row based on other column values